# How to send asynchronous Notification from server to android client

Tags: android, notifications

I should send asynchronous messages from my server to android application client. I want to implement something similar to a publish/subscribe pattern with a tls connection. Is it possible?
Thank you

Comment: this might a bit broad as it stands, have you tried anything or looked at any specific technologies ? asking `What kind of solution do you imagine? ` is quite broad and might even result in answers being based on opinion, which doesn't work here, unfortunately

Comment: @a_local_nobody I just edited following your advice

Comment: i doubt that makes much of a difference, perhaps have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info on how to approach this